# Draw a grid in Vue Konva

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

I have a Vue Konva stage that is draggable. In a background layer I have a visual grid with horizontal lines and vertical lines.
Now the grid needs to be zoomed, when the content is zoomed. The same goes for panning.
As you would go out of horizontal lines at the top if you scroll to the bottom, you have to translate the lines in a very special way. I did it with Vue and Canvas like this:

```
  drawGrid(translateX, translateY, gridSize){
    this.context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
    this.context.lineWidth = 1;

    //Horizontal grid-lines
    for (var t = 0.5; t < this.$refs.mainCanvas.height; t = t + gridSize * this.scaleFactor){
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.moveTo(0, t + translateY % (gridSize * this.scaleFactor));
      this.context.lineTo(this.$refs.mainCanvas.width, t + translateY % (gridSize * this.scaleFactor));
      this.context.stroke();
    }

    //Vertical grid-lines
    for (var t = 0.5; t < this.$refs.mainCanvas.width; t = t + gridSize * this.scaleFactor){
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.moveTo(t + translateX % (gridSize * this.scaleFactor), 0);
      this.context.lineTo(t + translateX % (gridSize * this.scaleFactor), this.$refs.mainCanvas.height);
      this.context.stroke();
    }}
```

Now, I want to do the same with Vue + Konva but I can't get it to run. My favourite way would be to have the lines in a template with a v-for directive.
I can't address the stage-width and height in the template, also the translation of the stage.

Is there any way to have a sleek version of this without a workaround?

Comment: Hi Nathan - I think the reason no one is responding is that your question is not well written for SO. I see you posted some code but what you posted is a small part of the bigger picture and you are asking people to spend a lot of time trying to work out what you are stuck on. Please produce a cut-down example of your issue using the advice you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then I am sure you will get better help.

Comment: You can create a custom shape that will draw your lines. You can your canvas code in `sceneFunc`.